# Can Java Observer and Observable be used in this case?

Tags: java, observable, observer-pattern

I have an Android application which I would to use the Java `Observer` and `Observable` classes to implement the Observer pattern to listen for a variable to change. I have simplified the problem into a compilable Java project.

Class that extends `Observable`

```
import java.util.Observable;

public class ServerResponse extends Observable {

    String request;
    String response;

    public ServerResponse() {}

    public ServerResponse(String reqquest) {
        //Process HTTP request here.
        //Notify observers that response has changed.
        response = "Sample HTTP response from server goes here.";
        setResponse(response);
    }

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(String response) {
        this.response = response;
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(response);
    }
}
```

Class that implements `Observer`

```
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

public class UserProfileActivity implements Observer {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Adding UserProfileActivity as an observer.");
        ServerResponse server = new ServerResponse();
        UserProfileActivity observer = new UserProfileActivity();
        server.addObserver(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
       System.out.println("Response obtained from server: " + o.toString());
    }

}
```

The problem I am experiencing is when I try to call `setResponse` in `ServerResonse.java`, the observer is not notified... but when I call `setResponse` in `UserProfileActivity.java`, the observer is able to get the notification. This behavior isn't what I expected.

The expected behavior that I want is for the `ServerResponse` class to be the one who calls `setResponse` after a response is received from the web server (this is all handled in `ServerResponse`).

Am I misunderstanding Java's `Observer` and `Observable` classes? I am confused as to why the `Observer` would be able to call `setResponse` within `ServerResponse` if the `Observer` is the one that should be getting the notification. It seems a little backwards to me.

Comment: Is this all the code, because I see nowhere a call to setResponse that would trigger the call to notifyObservers (apart from the unused constructor with a String parameter in ServerResponse).

Comment: Yes, I removed the line where I called `setResponse` in `UserProfileActivity` and `ServerResponse` because it did not provide the outcome that I wanted.

Comment: I think it is a misunderstanding of what Observable does.  When you call notifyObservers, it will not send messages or anything, it will just call the update method, for each Observer that registered itself, on the same thread.

Comment: From what I understand, a class that extends `Observable` allows `Observer`s to be notified when something withing `Observable` has changed. In my case it would be the String `response`. Then in my `update` of the `Observer`, I would use the information to update a view. Is that not correct?

Comment: Yes, but after you add the observer, you never call setResponse anywhere.

Comment: So `setResponse` HAS to be called within `UserProfileActivity`? Would it be possible to call `setResponse` within `ServerResponse` since that is where the data is being changed?

Comment: It's called from the main method's thread.  If you want you can move that method to another class, even into ServerResponse.  This is where I think the confusion is coming from... there's only 1 thread, there is no real "server", it all happens on the main thread...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134931/discussion-between-john16384-and-avp).

Answer (score 0):

I'll pick the code apart:

```
public ServerResponse(String reqquest) {
    //Process HTTP request here.
    //Notify observers that response has changed.
    response = "Sample HTTP response from server goes here.";
    setResponse(response);
}
```

This will never have the intended effect.  You just constructed a fresh Response class, and nobody has a reference to this anywhere.  So notifying anyone is pointless as nobody could have registered yet.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Adding UserProfileActivity as an observer.");
    ServerResponse server = new ServerResponse();
    UserProfileActivity observer = new UserProfileActivity();
    server.addObserver(observer);
}
```

Here you add an observer to `server`.  After that however the thread ends and the program exits.

Add something like this to actually get updates:

```
     for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         server.setResponse("New response " + i);
         Thread.sleep(1000);
     }
```

The update method gets called now.